# Getting the right created time with CSOM

Tags: csom

We have a csom list item operation, where we get one, and with `item["Created"]` we get the date and time of creation for the list item.

However the problem is that its always returning the UTC time, we are in GMT -5.

I have tried `Convert.ToDateTime(item["Created"]).ToLocalTime()`, and a few others but I havent been able to convert it to the local time, it alwas returns my time +5 hours.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add time zone offset

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
```